# How to warn developers of an unknown server type (only have version #) that it's leaking their client's credentials all over Google?

Tags: windows, security

This popular, but unknown server is leaking the admin login/pw all over Google, and I was wondering how to go about notifying the developer when all I have to go on is the information below.

```
 Server time : 2014/10/23 02:59:18.367
 Server Version : V4.3.3.1003
 Query Fields --> No Image Passed!
 Goodbye!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following link to identify servers [Web Server Information](http://browserspy.dk/webserver.php). It gives the following output for http://imageonthefly.autodatadirect.com/:

[image]

[Netcraft Toolbar](http://toolbar.netcraft.com) will give further information about technologies used on the site.

See http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=autodatadirect.com.

Comment: Thanks for that website, it's def something I will be using. However the answer it provided, was that the website uses IIS 7.x, which still doesn't answer my question regarding the Image Server Version : V4.3.3.1003 that is used by the above sites.

Comment: It's probably a homebrew server. I've been in that position before, using custom builds of something ...